# How to diagnose an old server hardware?

Tags: hardware-failure, diagnostic, hp-proliant

I have an old HP ProLiantML350 machine that I want to install Windows server 2012 on. Problem is I know that something is wrong with that server and Im looking for a way to diagnose that machine for hardware failures.

I already tried all build in options for diagnose and neither of them showed me whats wrong, but when I try to install an OS onto that server I get stuck in installation no matter what OS I use.

For example, the error I get when I try to install Windows Server 2012 while trying to format HDD is:

```
We couldn't create a new partition. [Error:0x800701e3].
```

Comment: We are not mind readers nor are we standing behind you watching your machine. Tell us very specifically what you have tried and what happens on each attempt. Use the formatting tools available so that your question is not just a wall of text. Be clear. "I get stuck in installation" does not tell us anything useful.

Comment: @Mokubai Edited, I hope it helps =)

Comment: So the Windows installer boots up, gets to the partition creation stage and then fails. Sounds like your hard drive is dead. Have you tried a different drive? Is the drive full? Can you see any partitions on the drive already? If so can you delete them?

Comment: @Mokubai nope, It has RAID system with 3 HDD's and I dont know how to test them all together to see which one works and which one doesn't. I could try to put a standard HDD to install the OS and then look whats up with that RAID.

Comment: If you care about the data then that would be the best way. Some RAID controllers also need you to give Windows the drivers on install. Usually you can put them on a memory stick and select add drivers on the disk install screen.

Comment: @Mokubai What if I dont care about data? I mean that server was out of use for like 2 years and now im trying to get it to work so I can use it as Data server, is there any other way I can fix this without inserting a new HDD?

Comment: @Mokubai Never mind, little bit of combinatorics and I found that broken HDD, thanks anyway =)

Comment: If you found out it was a dead drive it would be worthwhile posting that as an answer along with how you found out... might help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem, it was a dead drive. If you wanna know how I did it, well [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics). 3 drivers, 1 doesnt work.